# Views and joining content types on specific field in Drupal 7

Tags: 7, views

How can I 'LEFT OUTER JOIN' *or* 'LEFT JOIN' using Views in Drupal 7.

Here is what I'm trying to do, using an [example from Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29):

I have 2 content types: Employee's and Department's (tables below)

The "DepartmentID" noted in the Employee Table below in my case would be the NodeID of the department from the "Department" custom content type.

[image]

How can I use Drupal 7's Views module to Display a list of employees with the department name pulled from another content type as noted in the graphic below?

(The SQL statement below is really what I'm hoping to be able to do with the Views module, the table is the output I'm hoping to achieve.)

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In views 3 you have the **relationships** which manage JOINS between tables.
First you add your relation with the table and then in the next screen you can select *Require this relationship*.

[image: Relationship Views3]

If you check this checkbox, a `LEFT JOIN` will be made between the tables, if you uncheck it, it will generate a `LEFT OUTER JOIN`.

Comment: I needed to install References (http://drupal.org/project/reference as well for D7, but this is exactly what I was looking for.  Thank you @tostinni

Comment: what if now relationship is needed? for example in most visited content view there are all nodes including the ones which has not been visited till now. this does not need relationship