# joining profile types using views module

Tags: views, users

According to this thread, [click here](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/12894/views-and-joining-content-types-on-specific-field-in-drupal-7), I need to use `relationships` to inner join different content types.

I used the same method with profile types but I ended up with the following result.

Instead of using the views UI, do I need to custom code it?

Thanks

[image: image 1]

[image: image 2]

Answer (score 0):

Currently it's creating a join for each relationship (each profile type) that's why you see several rows. Question is what would happen if a user has several profile types (can they have that)?

You might get by with putting **Distinct** on your query.

In Views, fold out Advanced and look for Query settings under Other. Choose settings and check Distinct. Hit save.

[image]